# Get smoke color from flow object Vertex Color

Tags: smoke-simulation, volumetrics, vertex-colors

I have an alembic cache of an animated object with animated vertex color and I'm using this as a flow object for a smoke simulation.  All that is generating smoke well, but...

Does anyone know how I might get the Vert Color of my flow object to drive the color of the smoke?  I can get it to take the color attribute from the flow object settings in the dynamics tab, but not the shader color I've set up. Am I missing something simple, or is there a fancy workaround?

In case anyone wants to play with test files...

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_sFBv-aLhj5rua4PrwnVgxOrnW9lN8zd)

[Alembic source](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P0XoQOj24WfVC7DxV06nSqdLNeUWNQv6)

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because vertex colors are belongs to the flow model and the smoke's color belongs to the domain. The best what you can do is separating the model by the colors and adjust each of them in the smoke properties panel.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you very much for the reply.  I was hoping maybe there was a way to script a connection between the two.  Do you know a good way to separate meshes based on vertex color?